# Surface identification and fundamental group.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, non-orientable-surfaces

I am trying to identify and find the fundamental group of the surface $M,$ which is constructed by removing the shaded middle section from the surface below and replacing it with a four-holed Klein bottle and matching the holes.

[image]

For the fundamental group, I tried using van Kampen, where $U$ is the leftmost part of the surface, the Klein bottle in the middle, and a little bit of the rightmost part, and vice-versa for $V,$ but became stuck.

For simply identifying the surface, should I look at orientability and try to compute Euler characteristic?

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, orientability and euler characteristic is a much simpler way to go about it.

Comment: I see. I'm still having some trouble computing $\chi(M).$ I'm trying to use $\chi(M_1\#M_2)=\chi(M_1)+\chi(M_2)-2$ and look at this surface in three parts -- the leftmost torus, the Klein bottle, and the rightmost torus. So, is the Euler characteristic given by $\chi(T\#K\#T)=\chi(T)+\chi(T)+\chi(K)-4=0+0+0-4=-4$?

Comment: No, you are not doing a connected sum here.  You are cutting two discs and identifying two circles, rather than cutting one disc and identifying one circle.  So you need to modify that to account for the extra handle.